# Android camera preview flickering

Tags: android, android-camera

I was trying to write a simple camera app, but I ran into quite a frustrating problem with my picture preview. It shows horizontal flicker lines running up the screen. My screen has a width of 800 (Galaxy SII plus), so there are black spaces on the edges (the activity is set to horizontal orientation). Now these black margins begin to transition to a white-grey at the bottom ends when the flicker occurs, so I suspect there might be something drawn over them.
The really annoying part is that this does not seem to depend on the actual code, since it sometimes works without any flickering.

```
public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera camera;
    private Point size;

Preview(Context context, Camera camera, Point size) {
    super(context);
    this.camera = camera;
    this.size = size;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    parameters.setPreviewSize(720, 480);
    parameters.setPictureSize(720, 480);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.width,
            previewSize.height, Gravity.CENTER));

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.width,
            previewSize.height, Gravity.CENTER));

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        camera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {

}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    if (this.camera == camera) {
        return;
    }

    stopPreviewAndFreeCamera();

    this.camera = camera;

    if (this.camera != null) {
        requestLayout();

        try {
            this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.camera.startPreview();
    }

}

public void stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {

    if (this.camera != null) {
        this.camera.stopPreview();

        this.camera.release();

        this.camera = null;
    }
}

public void takePicture() {
    camera.autoFocus(null);
    camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureHandler(this.getContext()));
    camera.startPreview();
}
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Preview mPreview;

    .
    .
    .

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        this.mPreview.stopPreviewAndFreeCamera();
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
    }
```